# SEC7111 HTTPS Security compromise with UNC file path

Tags: security, internet-explorer, https, bookmarklet, unc

In writing a bookmarklet to load an external script via script tag injection, I've come across the SEC7111 Error in IE, but unlike all the other questions and answers I've found on this error, I don't believe I currently have the option of changing `http://` to `https://`, because I'm using `file://` to access a UNC path.

Full error sans impertinent details is:

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by file://server/share/sub/path/scripts/script-to-inject.js

I'm relatively open to the idea that my answer is that I'm "out of luck", but I'm hoping there's some way to set up an exception for this protocol or even a particular share. I'm especially hopeful because the file protocol is exclusively an intranet thing, so there's implicitly *more* trust - right? The bookmarklet functionality under development would only be in use by a few people, but I want to keep the main script off the application server and be able to update/enhance it without distributing the bookmarklet each time...

I'll be exploring alternative (HTTPS) server options, but is there a way to make IE tolerate `file://` addressed resources (UNC path) when specified in an HTTPS-served page?